# jxlsx - GridCommand pass method

Tags: jxl, jxls

In that example we're passing properties to `GridCommand`:

```
Context context = new Context();
                context.putVar("headers", Arrays.asList("PAYMENT", "NAME"));
                context.putVar("data", employees);
                JxlsHelper.getInstance().processGridTemplateAtCell(is, os, context, "payment,name", "Sheet2!A1");
```

Is it possible to pass method call ? like for exmaple: `getPayment()` instead of `payment` ?

Answer (score 0):

just `payment()` call should do the work (without "get" prefix)